# Error when creating a new item with Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using an Azure Function kicked by an HTTPTrigger. In that function, I am using the `CosmosClient` from `azure-cosmos`.

```
client = CosmosClient(endpoint, key)
database = client.get_database_client(database-name)
container = database.get_container_client(container-name)
container.create_item(body=req_body)
```

With the last line, I am trying to create an item with the object that I receive in the body of the HTTP request. I thought that Cosmos DB would automatically generate the id of the item. However, I am getting the following error:

```
Exception: CosmosHttpResponseError: (BadRequest) Message: {"Errors":["The input content is invalid because the required properties - 'id; ' - are missing"]}
```

Do I really need to assign an id to the item or am I missing anything? According to the documentation, the id can either be "System-generated or user-configurable"

[image]

Comment: My idea is that you can try to add property 'id' in your request to check if this 'id' results in the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id` is a required attribute. Some older SDKs had the option to autogenerate it as a Guid, but newer SDKs opt for transparency and giving the user the choice explicitly. You could use a Guid or any other value that is relevant for you.